# Binary classification using xgboost

Tags: xgboost, class-imbalance, outlier, binary-classification, categorical-encoding

Why when adding new features in my ADS for a binary classification using XGBOOST my score and uplift has decreased ? What is the best way to treate categorical features or other features in order that the performance of the model won't decrease ?
Ps.

1. I have skewed data so in my pipeline I created PowerTransformer()
2. I Have very imbalanced data, so I used undersampling.
3. I have outliers that I can't delete or replace due to the fact that I don't have many rows
4. for categorical features I encoded them using LabelEncoder().

Thank you ?